# Gaussian Definite Integral for Gaussian random variables

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, expectation

> Weh have the following:
>
> For $s>0$, $$\int_s^{\infty} e^{-x^2/2}\,\mathrm{d}x \le \frac 1 s e^{-s^2/ 2}, \quad \int_s^{\infty} e^{-x^2/2}\,\mathrm{d}x \le \sqrt {\frac \pi 2} e^{-s^2/ 2}.$$
> Then prove that for a random variable $X \sim N(0,1)$ and $s>0$, $$ \Pr(X>s) \le \frac 1 {\sqrt {2\pi}}\min\left({\frac 1 t, \sqrt {\frac \pi 2}}\right)e^{-s^2/2}.$$

So far i have the following $\Pr(X>s) = \int_s^{\infty} e^{-x^2}\,\mathrm{d}x \le \min\left(\frac 1 t,  {\frac \pi 2}\right) e^{-s^2/2},$, which does not need any further proof if i get first the two inequalities right?

I got the first part where it is $\le 1/s$ but for the second part, I tried converting to polar coordinates for the second equation. Since I did  $$\int_s^{\infty} e^{-x^2/2}\,\mathrm{d}x \int_s^{\infty} e^{-y^2/2}\,\mathrm{d}y \le \int_0^{\pi/2} \int_s^{\infty} e^{-r^2/2}\,r\mathrm{d}rd\theta \to \int_s^{\infty} e^{-x^2/2}\,\mathrm{d}x \le \sqrt {\frac \pi 2 e^{-s^2/ 2}}$$? Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: no it does not please elaborate

Comment: i plugged in a calculator as well and it equals to e^-s^2/2

Comment: Yes, you are right. I will find another way to explain your inequality.

Answer (score 1):

Just make a parallel transition fits:

$$
\begin{align}\int_s^\infty \int_s^\infty e^{-(x^2+y^2)/2}dxdy 
&= \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty e^{-((x+s)^2+(y+s)^2)/2}dxdy
\\&= e^{-s^2} \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty e^{-(x^2+y^2)/2} e^{-2s(x+y)}dxdy
\\&\le e^{-s^2} \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty e^{-(x^2+y^2)/2}dxdy = \frac{\pi}{2} e^{-s^2}
\end{align}$$

Comment: wow that is very smart thank you so its not possible to integrate purely from s to infinity for dr? why is that? like why would i get the wrong answer when trying to use polar?

Comment: @TomWangzilin The idea using polar coordinate is right. The only problem is we get a loose bound if we did not make any transition.

Comment: what do you mean by transition? and in part, is ther a way to use polar still to get the result desired? just out of curiosity

Comment: also why the inequality? when 2t(x+Y)<1, e^-2t(x+Y)>1 so integral can be bigger?

Comment: @TomWangzilin I mean a [translation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_(geometry)).  I have no idea what happens if $s<0$.

Comment: right, i understand the translation part but not the inequality part why is the second line smaller than third?

Comment: @TomWangzilin This is because $e^{-2s(x+y)}\le 1$. Notice that both $s$, $x$ and $y$ are non-negative.

Comment: thats what i am confused bout sorry, but it is possible for $e^{-2s(x+y)} \ge 1$ if we have a small s such as 0.001 then 2s(x+y)}<1

Comment: @TomWangzilin You don't worry such possibility. $e^x\le1$ iff $x\le0$.

Comment: oh i see i totally forgot calculs but now i got it thanks again

Comment: if youre free, i would like to just ask if it is possible  to use polar cordinates like the following: $$\int_s^{\infty} e^{-x^2/2}\,\mathrm{d}x \int_s^{\infty} e^{-y^2/2}\,\mathrm{d}y \le \int_0^{\pi/2} \int_s^{\infty} e^{-r^2/2}\,r\mathrm{d}rd\theta \le \mathrm{d}y \le \int_0^{\pi/2} \int_s^{\infty} e^{-r^2}\,r\mathrm{d}rd\theta$$ because if so then we would get the desired result, or it is not posisble to use polar coords here to derive the result i want?

Comment: @TomWangzilin This is what you already tried, and you know what happens after the last term of your inequality.